# Custom action when iBeacon is in reach with Apple Wallet

Tags: ibeacon, beacon, wallet, passkit

I would like to create a pass for Apple Wallet, where I could update the pass when it is near a beacon.

As I found [here](https://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2015/10/06/passkit-with-beacons.html), it is possible to show a pass from the wallet, when you are near the beacon.

That's how you create the beacon, but you can't really specify, what should happen if you are near a beacon.

```
"beacons" : [
      {
        "major" : 2,
        "minor" : 150,
        "proximityUUID" : "2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6",
        "relevantText" : "RadBeacon Athletic Club Front Desk"
      }
    ]
```

Is there a possibility to update the pass/make a custom request or is this the default action from Apple Wallet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn’t possible unfortunately.

Apple view location data as personal.  Being able to update a pass based on location or proximity to a beacon would require an API call to be able to update the pass.

That would require an Apple app (Wallet) to disclose that the user is in proximity of the beacon (personal data), to a third party developer.  This has too many privacy implications which is why it is not allowed.

The beacon implementation in Wallet is designed to add convenience.  It allows the pass to be pushed to the lock screen right when the user needs it (E.g. waiting in line at a register or at the checkin counter).  Trying to use it for any other purpose will often end with a bad user experience.